# Linux lite iso successfully flashed to usb but not booting

Tags: linux, boot, usb, iso-image

I have the latest **linux lite 4.4 iso** dowloaded from the official website. After that I flashed it to adata 16GB usb stick. I tried **rufus**, **unetbootin** and **etcher**(as suggested in the website). In case of **rufus** and **unetbootin** the usb is successfully booted like my experience of installing ubuntu and windows several times previously. But when from the bootloader list of my device I selected the usb stick. Nothing happens and it goes directly to bios menu. I tried several times also tried re-downloading the iso but the situation is same. I have booted several versions of ubuntu, debian and windows this way successfully. But does linux lite requires some different formats? 
Secondly in case of **etcher** my usb is not even detected. It only shows windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 that is previously installed in my device. Also windows 10 is not able to read the  data after flashing by **etcher**. After format it becomes 1.3GB insted of 14.4GB in normal case. What is the actual problem? Is my device not compatible or the iso or softwares I used is not working correctly? (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: How are you getting your computer to boot the USB? From changing the boot device in BIOS, or from a BIOS menu like pressing F10 or F12, etc? Or from your main hard drive's bootloader? From the line *"But when from the bootloader list of my device"* it sounds like your main drive is listing other devices it finds... Etcher sounds like it might be doing a raw / dd copy of the iso to the usb, so the size sounds normal (if the iso is about 1.3G)

Comment: @Xen2050 pressing **ESC**. When flashed by etcher usb does not even shows up in bios menu.

Comment: @Tangent I've encountered the same issue. Despite the official download page specifying Etcher, the live USB is not detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well I think the issue is because I had the wrong iso.**

I googled for linux lite iso outside the official site. What I noticed they do not support UEFI mode. I firstly didn't know that. But for others like me here is something might work

As they say in this thread:
[UEFI not supported in linux lite](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/introductions/uefi-and-linux-lite/)

But there is a uefi build what I found on another thread might be buggy though as it is in testing case.

1. [Thread](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/linux-lite-software-development/uefi-build-test/msg44253/#msg44253)
2. [.iso file](http://repo.linuxliteos.com/uefitests/4.2/)

I have used it already. Really a good fluent and stable experience.